# How do I access data from structure of another class?

Tags: objective-c, properties, struct

I've created structure and want to access data from it in another class. So, I've created property but got an error "Property dfi not found on object of type File". What I'm doing wrong?

```
//File.h
typedef struct 
{
    double *data;
    int a;    
} DataFileInfo;

@interface File : NSObject {

    DataFileInfo dfi;
}

@property DataFileInfo dfi;

//File.m
@implementation File

@synthesize dfi;
```

In `File2` class  I'm trying access that property

```
//File2.m
@implementation File2

File *file = [[File alloc]init];

double *b = file.dfi.data; // error "Property dfi not found on object of type File".
```

Comment: I'm guessing that the compiler is confused because you declared a property of type `DataFileInfo` vs `DataFileInfo*` and it doesn't know how to handle that.  Plus, with a non-Objective-C type for the property, you should probably explicitly specify `assign` or whatever access technique the property should have.

Comment: Why don't you use an object instead of a struct?

Comment: I would recommend renaming your class.  File is highly likely to conflict with a standard or third-party framework.  Use `AppnameFile` or similar.

Comment: @Flex_Addicted tried with object. Same error. Bizzare! :-)

Comment: @andrey -- I don't see how you could have tried with an Objective-C object, since you can't embed an instance of one Obj-C object inside another (vs embedding a reference).

Answer (score 0):

Change `@property DataFileInfo dfi;` to:

`@property (nonatomic, readonly) DataFileInfo* dfi;`.

Then remove the `@synthesize` and, in its place code:

```
(DataFileInfo*) dfi {
    return &dfi;
}
```